# How can one specify a default namespace for C++/cli project?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

In a C# project the project properties allows one to specify a default namespace. I am using C++/cli to write third party plugins for a project that uses reflection to parse the default namespace. However, I cannot find out how to specify a default namespace for a C++/cli project.

How does one specify a default namespace for a C++/cli project.

**Correction**
So apparently that wasn't the issue.
Thanks for the clarification that assemblies don't have default namespaces. I had assumed the default namespace was parsed because there was a C# project template they provided in which the default namespace had to be the same as the namespace of the plugin classes you created or the plugin would not be found. Must be something about the project template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting in a C# project does very little.  It doesn't get passed to the compiler, it merely sets the namespace name that is used for any auto-generated code inserted into a source code file when you add a new file to the project.  The C++ IDE uses the project name as the default namespace name.  Readily changed by the programmer.

There is no concept of "default namespace" at the assembly level.  You are looking for the wrong solution.